# Why does this x86 shellcode run successfully but then trigger a violation executing location?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86, shellcode

**Question:** Why does the program throw a violation executing location exception after the shellcode accomplishes it's goal successfully?

**Description:** My objective was to load and unload a DLL into the current program using x86 shellcode that calls Windows API functions. While the program accomplishes this goal successfully, Visual Studio then tells me there is a violation executing a location. I know the program executes successfully because the test DLL file prints when it attaches and detaches. Another important detail to note is this only occurs when calling the unloading function, the loading function works with absolutely no problems. *(I am doing this on Windows 10 in Visual Studio 2019 using C++20 if that's important)*

I'm aware that the shellcode does not properly set up the stack frame, but I made sure ESP is set back to normal before returning execution to the callee function. I saved EAX and set it back to normal in the unloading function too. I made this test program with the end goal to produce shellcode I can use for a remote thread context patching method in a dll injection program I am working on. Also I have verified the offsets used to find the return addresses multiple times. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Here is the console output.

> Attached! DLLMain at 0x79EF134D
> Detached!

Here is the exception thrown.

> Exception thrown at 0x9269D814 in Shellcode DLL
> Loading.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing
> location 0x9269D814.

Here is the main file, it is only around 120 lines.

```
const dword follow_relative_jump(const pbyte pointer)
{
    if (pointer)
    {
        if (pointer[0] == 0xE9 || pointer[0] == 0xEB)
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<dword>(pointer + 5 + reinterpret_cast<psdword>(pointer + 1)[0]);
        }
    }


    return reinterpret_cast<dword>(pointer);
}

void load_dll(const dword path_address)
{
    /*
        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (return address buffer)

        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (LoadLibraryA() address buffer)
        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (DLL path address buffer)
        FF 54 24 04         -> call [esp + 4]       (calling LoadLibraryA())
        83 C4 08            -> add esp, 8           (cleaning up the stack, except for return address)

        C3                  -> ret                  (return to return address that was pushed first, it should pop it off the stack and return ESP to normal)
    */

    std::vector<byte> shellcode = {
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0xFF, 0x54, 0x24, 0x04,
        0x83, 0xC4, 0x08,
        0xC3
    };


    // Offset is the distance from the function prologue to the next instruction after the call to load_dll()
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 1)[0] = follow_relative_jump(reinterpret_cast<pbyte>(&load_dll)) + 0x22C;
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 6)[0] = reinterpret_cast<dword>(&LoadLibraryA);
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 11)[0] = path_address;



    if (const auto allocation = VirtualAlloc(NULL, shellcode.size(), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE))
    {
        memcpy(allocation, shellcode.data(), shellcode.size());
        reinterpret_cast<void(__cdecl*)()>(allocation)();
        VirtualFree(allocation, shellcode.size(), MEM_FREE);
    }
}

void unload_dll(const dword path_address)
{
    /*
        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (return address buffer)
        50                  -> push eax             (save EAX so we can set it back later)

        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (GetModuleHandleA() address buffer)
        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (DLL path address buffer)
        FF 54 24 04         -> call [esp + 4]       (calling GetModuleHandleA())
        83 C4 08            -> add esp, 8           (clean up the stack, except for return address and saved EAX)

        68 90 90 90 90      -> push 0x????????      (FreeLibrary() address buffer)
        50                  -> push eax             (Handle to module returned by GetModuleHandleA() in EAX)
        FF 54 24 04         -> call [esp + 4]       (calling FreeLibrary())
        83 C4 08            -> add esp, 8           (clean up stack, except for return address and saved EAX)

        58                  -> pop eax              (set back EAX to what it was before)
        C3                  -> ret                  (return to return address that was pushed first, it should pop it off the stack and return ESP to normal)
    */

    std::vector<byte> shellcode = {
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0x50,
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0xFF, 0x54, 0x24, 0x04,
        0x83, 0xC4, 0x08,
        0x68, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90,
        0x50,
        0xFF, 0x54, 0x24, 0x04,
        0x83, 0xC4, 0x08,
        0x58,
        0xC3
    };


    // Offset is the distance from the function prologue to the next instruction after the call to unload_dll()
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 1)[0] = follow_relative_jump(reinterpret_cast<pbyte>(&unload_dll)) + 0x2AF;
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 7)[0] = reinterpret_cast<dword>(&GetModuleHandleA);
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 12)[0] = path_address;
    reinterpret_cast<pdword>(shellcode.data() + 24)[0] = reinterpret_cast<dword>(&FreeLibrary);



    if (const auto allocation = VirtualAlloc(NULL, shellcode.size(), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE))
    {
        memcpy(allocation, shellcode.data(), shellcode.size());
        reinterpret_cast<void(__cdecl*)()>(allocation)();
        VirtualFree(allocation, shellcode.size(), MEM_FREE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* path = "C:\\Users\\maxbd\\Desktop\\test.dll";


    load_dll(reinterpret_cast<dword>(path));
    unload_dll(reinterpret_cast<dword>(path));


    static_cast<void>(std::getchar());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `LoadLibraryA` is `stdcall` meaning it removes the arguments itself, you should not do that.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know that. Thanks I’ll see if it fixes it when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't consider the calling conventions of the functions I was trying to call and how they are expected to operate. The Windows API functions use `__stdcall` which pops the function arguments off the stack within the function. So I should only be popping off the function address I pushed and not the function arguments. Thanks for the information in your comment, Jester.

<s>Also, I had to change the `0xC3` return instruction to `0xC2 0x04 0x00` so that it would pop the return address off the stack. I thought that the normal `0xC3` return would do that for me, but apparently it didn't. Or at least it doesn't in this case for some reason. Visual Studio throws an exception about ESP being incorrect if I don't pop it off manually. If I do, it works perfectly in both loading and unloading the DLL.</s>

I also completely forgot that since this is a test program I am calling the shellcode as a `__cdecl` function using a function pointer instead of hijacking the execution of a remote thread and modifying EIP, so the `call` instruction is being used so I have no reason to push the return address manually. <s>I'm assuming my voluntary failure to properly set up the stack frame is the reason for the return behavior being abnormal, as the return address should be above EBP.</s> Because `call` is used, the return address is pushed twice, so the return instruction that pops off a dword after returning is needed to get rid of the automatically pushed return address. When I apply the shellcode to my actual program I will try a relative jump instead of a return, it makes more sense in this case and it's neater.

I wouldn't be surprised if I'm misunderstanding this solution, but it seems to work so I will consider this solved.

Comment: `C3 ret` *does* pop the return address off the stack.  You only need `ret 4` if your caller expects you to pop an *arg*, i.e. it's assuming that this function is also stdcall or another callee-pops convention, with one arg.  That might well be the default for 32-bit code.

Comment: I think it has something to do with me not setting up the base pointer so that the return address is above it, I will keep it like this though unless I find it causes problems in more testing.

Comment: `ret` has zero interaction with EBP.  You need ESP pointing at the return address when `ret` executes.  Afterwards, ESP points above it (and possibly higher than that if you use C2 ret imm16).  You caller is expecting ESP to either have the same value it did on entry, or to be n * 4 bytes higher for callee-pops conventions.  Disassembling the calling function should make that clear, although not that even for caller-pops the popping might be deferred to reuse the same arg space for multiple calls.

Comment: After reading your updated answer, yeah if execution reached your block via a hijacked jump or ret, then you might not have a return address on the stack on entry to your "function".  In that case yes, relative jump can make sense if your injected code is a known distance from the target code (no ASLR, or in a static buffer).  And yes, you may need to adjust the stack to match where you're "returning" to vs. where you came from.

Comment: Oh, okay thanks. So I am assuming in this case what's happening is my return instruction is actually using the return address I pushed manually, and then popping off four bytes which would be the return address pushed by call, which sets the ESP back to how it was before. Also why I wasn't experiencing any problems before with the original load function despite it popping off one two many dwords from the stack.